# Radio Button Unresponsive on some iOS devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, radio-button

I'm encountering a problem where radio buttons work inconsistently.

The buttons only respond on some touch devices (iPhone & iPad) when the right side of the outer element is touched.

Desktop works fine.

If the user touches the radio button directly the button doesn't respond.

The weird thing is this doesn't happen on all touch devices. Some will work fine while others won't.

I tested on iPhone X and it works fine but iPhone 11 and iPad don't.

It works on mobile Chrome but not Safari and Firefox.

I've included the js, HTML, and css of one radio button below.

Thanks for you any help.

**Js**

```
document.querySelector("#s89fdf874ee_services > li:nth-child(1) > div > label")
```

**HTML**

```
<label><div class="icheckbox_square-blue checked"><input type="checkbox" id="s89fdf874ee_services_0" name="s89fdf874ee[services][]" value="2" checked="checked" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden;"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins></div><span class="control-label__text">
                Buyback</span></label>
```

**CSS**

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    --zd_bold: LatoBold,var(--zd_fallback_font);
    --zd_heavy: LatoHeavy,var(--zd_fallback_font);
    --zd_fallback_font: -apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif;
    --zd_regular: LatoRegular,var(--zd_fallback_font);
    --zd_semibold: LatoSemibold,var(--zd_fallback_font);
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-left: -20px;
```

Comment: Could you make your code into a snippet that we can run to see the problem for ourselves (make sure it shows the problem) as it sounds as though you have some other element overlapping the radio button on smaller devices, but the code you have given wouldn't show that, there being no other elements. Thanks.

Comment: I’m using symfony 3.3 field checkboxtype. Not sure how to create an executable snippet for this. So you think and overlapping element might be causing this issue?

Comment: Can you use your devtools on your browser to test at different device widths and see if you can recreate the problem there? I find giving every element a (different) background-color with opacity < 1 helps with this sort of debugging as you can see where they all are in relation to each other z axis-wise.

Comment: test here https://3w1.website/admin/ user:

Comment: This seems to require a login.

Comment: test here https://3w1.website/admin/ 

user: sellmyiphonemiami@gmail.com
pw: abc123

find problem at https://3w1.website/admin/admin-inventory-item/118/edit

see radio button at the bottom in the filters section

Comment: I have checked the HTML of that Wordpress backend page with W3C validator. There are errors including two instances of a body element. I think you may need to get in touch with the Symfony maintainers as it's looking messy (and may or may not be causing your problem).

Comment: Can you explain how to check for this error? So you think this is a symfony problem?

Comment: I just copied all the HTML using my browser dev tools Edit HTML option and put it through W3C validator. I don't know whether the two body elements causes a problem, but having (allegedly) two body elements looks odd anyway.

Comment: Scrap that comment on body tags - a red herring.

Comment: We’re you able to recreate the behavior on your phone or dev tools? What would you do next to debug?

Comment: Yes, try ith your dev tools, giving olors to each of th elements so you can see how they fit together.

Comment: Is there an addon in phpstorm or your ide thats good for debugging front end bugs or you use dev tools?

Comment: devtools in Chrome

Comment: Maybe increasing the clickable area can fix this.

Comment: I found the problem. Safari’s ‘request desktop website’ was active  which caused the radio buttons to not work properly. So even though the site was responsive and appeared exactly as the mobile version, the selections buttons didn’t work. So all I had to do was request mobile website and it worked. Not sure why the default was desktop on my phone but it was this simple fix.